# jQuery hold form submit until "continue" button pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui

I am trying to submit a form, which I have had working, but have now modified it to include a modal jQuery UI box, so that it won't submit until the user presses "continue". I've had various problems with this, including getting the form to hold until that button is pressed, but I think I have found a solution to that, but implementing it, I am getting a SyntaxError which I can't find the source of.

With the help of kevin B managed to find the answer was the form was submitting, but the returned JSON response wasn't quite formatted right. The response was that the form wasn't being submitted, so that problem is still occurring.

So updated the code with the provided feedback, now need to find out why the form isnt submitting. I know its something to do with the 2nd function isnt recognising the submit button has been pressed, so need to know how to submit that form data without the form needing to be submitted again.

Below is the new code:

```
function submitData() {
$("#submitProvData").submit(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    var gTotal, sTotal, dfd;
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
    $("#submitProvData input").css("border", "1px solid #aaaaaa");
    $("#submitProvData input[readonly='readonly']").css("border", "none");
    sTotal = $('#summaryTotal').val();
    gTotal = $('#gptotal').val();
    if(gTotal !== 'sTotal'){
        $("#newsupinvbox").append('<div id="newsupinvdiagbox" title="Warning - Totals do not match" class="hidden"><p>Press "Continue", to submit the invoice flagged for attention.</p> <br /><p class="italic">or</p><br /> <p>Press "Correct" to correct the discrepancy.</p></div>') //CREATE DIV
        //SET
        $("#newsupinvdiagbox").dialog({
            resizable: false,
            autoOpen:false,
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            width:380,
            height:240,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            position: ['center',20],
            buttons: {
                'Continue': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                    reData();
                }, // end continue button
                'Correct': function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                        return false;
                    } //end cancel button
                }//end buttons
            });//end dialog
            $('#newsupinvdiagbox').dialog('open');
        }
        return false;
    });
}

function reData() {
    console.log('submitted');
    $("#submitProvData").submit(function(resubmit){
        console.log('form submit');
        var formData;
        formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "functions/invoicing_upload_provider.php",
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function(result) {
                $.each($.parseJSON(result), function(item, value){
                    if(item == 'Success'){    
                        $('#newsupinv_window_message_success_mes').html('The provider invoice was uploaded successfully.');
                        $('#newsupinv_window_message_success').fadeIn(300, function (){
                            reset();
                        }).delay(2500).fadeOut(700);
                    } else if(item == 'Error'){      
                        $('#newsupinv_window_message_error_mes').html(value);
                        $('#newsupinv_window_message_error').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(700);
                    } else if(item == 'Warning'){      
                        $('#newsupinv_window_message_warning_mes').html(value);
                        $('#newsupinv_window_message_warning').fadeIn(300, function (){
                            reset();
                        }).delay(2500).fadeOut(700);
                    } 
                });
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#newsupinv_window_message_error_mes').html("An error occured, the form was not submitted");
                $('#newsupinv_window_message_error').fadeIn(300);
                $('#newsupinv_window_message_error').delay(3000).fadeOut(700);
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
}
```

[image: Original console errors]

Comment: I seriously doubt you need to unbind/bind the event at all. You likely just need to bind the event once and not rebind it.

Comment: Could you provide us with a JSFiddle?

Comment: Basically, bind to the submit event, immediately prevent the default, do any validation that is needed, then open the dialog. When the continue button in the dialog is clicked, force the form to submit using `$(theform)[0].submit()`, which bypasses the jquery bound event.

Comment: Or, better yet, since you're submitting with ajax, drop the deferred objects completely and just move the ajax to the click handler of the continue button.. Seems like you are making this WAY more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: *"I am getting a SyntaxError which I can't find the source of."* what do you mean you can't find the source of? you must be able to see a line number.

Comment: What does `new FormData($(this)[0])` reference in the scope of a deferred ?

Comment: @KevinB thanks for your input. Im not hugely experienced here and not up with all the terminology, if you could provide an example, that would be great. In terms of the syntaxerror, it directing to line 2 of the jQuery.js file

Comment: Are you using a javascript debugger (google chrome console or firebug)?

Comment: Google Chrome Console

Comment: On the error,there should be a down arrow. When you click it, teh error will expand with more information. Next, look to the far right side of the console, you'll see different line numbers, and a few (anonymous function) things. What you're looking for is the first thing that points to your code

Comment: Edited the post with the image of the messages in the console, from the lines that has given me, I cannot see any errors, but then I could just be blind and missing them.

Comment: is `reset` defined? Can you give a sample of the json being returned from the server? (network tab, click xhr, cause request to happen, click on request, then go to response -> preview

Comment: @KevinB solved that mystery, but still having issues getting the form data to submit after the button pressed.

Comment: Rather than binding a submit event in `rdata()`, just execute the code. `//$("#submitProvData").submit(function(resubmit){`

Comment: @KevinB attempted that, but it doesn't actually submit the data. Even tried:
formData = new FormData($("#submitProvData")[0]);
but no data is sent, so i get the response from the server the form wasnt submitted, which is a custom message i made.

Answer (score 0):

With much help from Kevin B, managed to get the form working as I wanted. The form now submits, the answer lay in using .serialise() rather than FormData to get the form to finally submit correctly.

Posted below is the completed code:

```
function submitData() {
$("#submitProvData").submit(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
    var gTotal, sTotal, dfd;
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
    $("#submitProvData input").css("border", "1px solid #aaaaaa");
    $("#submitProvData input[readonly='readonly']").css("border", "none");
    sTotal = $('#summaryTotal').val();
    gTotal = $('#gptotal').val();
    if(gTotal !== 'sTotal'){
        $("#newsupinvbox").append('<div id="newsupinvdiagbox" title="Warning - Totals do not match" class="hidden"><p>Press "Continue", to submit the invoice flagged for attention.</p> <br /><p class="italic">or</p><br /> <p>Press "Correct" to correct the discrepancy.</p></div>') //CREATE DIV
            //SET
            $("#newsupinvdiagbox").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen:false,
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                width:380,
                height:240,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                position: ['center',20],
                buttons: {
                    'Continue': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        reData();
                    }, // end continue button
                    'Correct': function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        return false;
                    } //end cancel button
                }//end buttons
            });//end dialog
            $('#newsupinvdiagbox').dialog('open');
        } else {
            reData(); //CONTINUE WITH FORM SUBMIT
        }
        return false;
    });
}

function reData() {
    var formData;
    formData = $("#submitProvData").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "functions/invoicing_upload_provider.php",
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $.each($.parseJSON(result), function(item, value){
                if(item == 'Success'){    
                    $('#newsupinv_window_message_success_mes').html('The provider invoice was uploaded successfully.');
                    $('#newsupinv_window_message_success').fadeIn(300, function (){
                        reset();
                    }).delay(2500).fadeOut(700);
                } else if(item == 'Error'){      
                    $('#newsupinv_window_message_error_mes').html(value);
                    $('#newsupinv_window_message_error').fadeIn(300).delay(3000).fadeOut(700);
                } else if(item == 'Warning'){      
                    $('#newsupinv_window_message_warning_mes').html(value);
                    $('#newsupinv_window_message_warning').fadeIn(300, function (){
                        reset();
                    }).delay(2500).fadeOut(700);
                } 
            });
        },
        error: function() {
            $('#newsupinv_window_message_error_mes').html("An error occured, the form was not submitted");
            $('#newsupinv_window_message_error').fadeIn(300);
            $('#newsupinv_window_message_error').delay(3000).fadeOut(700);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A complete system to break form and post with jquery/ajax

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('#form_sendemail').submit(function(e) {
$.ajax({
  url: 'sendmail.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
    //
    $('#form_sendemail .has-error').removeClass('has-error');
    $('#form_sendemail .help-block').html('').hide();
    $('#form_message').removeClass('alert-success').html('');
  },
  success: function( json, textStatus ) {
    if( json.error ) {
      // Error messages
      if( json.error.name ) {
        $('#form_sendemail input[name="name"]').parent().addClass('has-error');
        $('#form_sendemail input[name="name"]').next('.help-block').html( json.error.name ).slideDown();
      }
      if( json.error.email ) {
        $('#form_sendemail input[name="email"]').parent().addClass('has-error');
        $('#form_sendemail input[name="email"]').next('.help-block').html( json.error.email ).slideDown();
      }
      if( json.error.message ) {
        $('#form_sendemail textarea[name="message"]').parent().addClass('has-error');
        $('#form_sendemail textarea[name="message"]').next('.help-block').html( json.error.message ).slideDown();
      }
    }
    //
    if( json.success ) {
      $('#form_message').addClass('alert-success').html( json.success ).slideDown();

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#form_message').slideUp("fast", function() {
          $(this).removeClass('alert-success').html('');
         });
      },4000);
      $('#form_sendemail')[0].reset();
    }

  },
  complete: function( XMLHttpRequest, textStatus ) {
    //
  }
});

return false;
});
});
```